# OWIN Authentication - redirect loop - The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to use OWIN Authentication with **just** google authentication
ie - users of my app exist only if they have a google account

I've configured my Auth Config like this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "External",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/authentication"),
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "xxx123",
            ClientSecret = "xxx456",
        });
    }
}
```

My `AuthenticationController` has an Index method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback")
    });

    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

When I got to a restricted page, I get

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

... it is hitting my AuthenticationControllers Index method many many times...

Any idea what I've not configured correctly?

**EDIT**

My `ExternalLoginCallback` looks like:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{

}
```

Note - this method is never hit, if I put a breakpoint on it

Comment: Does your `ExternalLoginCallback` action have `[AllowAnonymous]`?

Comment: What's your redirecting url looks like?

Comment: Added ExternalLoginCallback

Comment: So you are always returning `HttpUnauthorizedResult` from you `Index` action? and that redirects you to `"/authentication"`

Comment: No, the Index action of the Home controller (for example) is marked with [Authorize] - the Index action shown in above code is on AuthenticationController - ie /authentication - it calls Authentication.Challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I wasn't passing in the provider type to the `Challenge` method -

Changing my Index action method to:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback")
        };

        //challenge
        Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, "Google");

        //if above didn't handle it, return unauth.
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
```